# Is there alternative way to access session details in deferred custom action?

Tags: session, wix, windows-installer, custom-action

I have a custom action and need to get below values for copying some parts from installation folder to VS2010 folder

1. VS2010 directory path (`VS2010DEVENV` property)
2. Installation path (`INSTALLLOCATION` property)

To give enough privileges, I've set custom action as `Execute='deferred' Impersonate='no'`. But when running the installer, it logged the message:

> Cannot access session details from a non-immediate custom action

It seems we cannot access a property in a "deferred" custom action (i.e `session["VS2010DEVENV"]`)

Is there any other way so that I can retrieve those values as needed?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370543.aspx) must be helpful. Pay special attention to the bottom of the page, a guideline of 2 steps how to pass values via [CustomActionData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2w2fhwzz(v=vs.80).aspx).

Here is the excerpt:

> To write the value of a property into the installation script for use
>   during a deferred execution custom action:
>
> 1. Insert a small custom action into the installation sequence that sets the property of interest to a property having the same name as
>      the deferred execution custom action. For example, if the primary key
>      for the deferred execution custom action is "MyAction" set a property
>      named "MyAction" to the property X which you need to retrieve. You
>      must set the "MyAction" property in the installation sequence before
>      the "MyAction" custom action. Although any type of custom action can
>      set the context data, the simplest method is to use a property
>      assignment custom action (for example Custom Action Type 51).
> 2. At the time when the installation sequence is processed, the installer will write the value of property X into the execution script
>      as the value of the property CustomActionData.

Comment: Thanks for the [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370543.aspx). The **CustomActionData** property works well. But I'm wondering how we can pass more than one value. In my case, I need both VS2010 and installation folder values. Can you give some hints if possible?

Comment: You'll have to parse the string you pass in the deferred custom action. For instance, you can pass `[VS2010DEVENV]|[INSTALLLOCATION]`, and split the CustomActionData by `|` in deferred CA. If you use DTF for your CA, it has a dictionary-like CustomActionData property, and you can pass it like `vs2010=[VS2010DEVENV];location=[INSTALLLOCATION]`, and obtain it like `session.CustomActionData["vs2010"]` and `session.CustomActionData["location"]`

Comment: Great! It totally solves my case. Thank you so much for your advices.

Comment: CustomActionData link broken (page says "This Topic Is No Longer Available"). But this is pointing me in the right direction, thanks!

Comment: Is there a way, I can send all the properties present in the installation script to the Custom Action? I Have used this method, but I am unable to get the INSTALLLOCATION OR INSTALLDIR property, although I receive the TARGETDIR property.

Comment: Can this set property values as well?

Answer (score 25):

Additional details: multiple property values can be passed by using the following syntax in a "Custom Action Type 51" (which is basically just a custom action that sets a property value):

```
PROPERTY1=Value1;PROPERTY2=Value2;PROPERTY3=...
```

Values can be retrieved from within the custom action like this:

```
string prop1 = session.CustomActionData["PROPERTY1"];
string prop2 = session.CustomActionData["PROPERTY2"];
```

Here's an example that sets property values for a custom action with ID "MyCustomAction":

```
<CustomAction
  Id="SetCustomActionPropertyValues"
  Property="MyCustomAction"
  Value="INSTALLDIR=[INSTALLDIR];EXECUTABLE=[#MyExecutableFile]" />
```

*(read [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa368609.aspx) for more details on the formatted syntax which in this example is used to retrieve the install location of a file with ID "MyExecutableFile")*

Comment: Many thanks for the concrete example. Just what I needed. Future visitors should also see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11233268/660536) for further details and examples.